# NSThread issue how to resolve?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I m writting the following code.

```
#import <objc/objc.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myT :NSObject
-(void) startT;
-(void) tfun;
@end

@implementation myT 
-(void) tfun
{
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSLog (@"Inside thread Function .. ");
[pool drain];
}

-(void) startT
{
  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(tfun) toTarget:self withObject:nil ];
}
@end

int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{
   myT *t = [[myT alloc] init];
   [t startT];
   return 0;
}
```

it compiles, and leads to run time error. what i am doing wrong ? i am familiar with pthread. how can i wait till the thread completes, ie: pthread_wait kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can spin the run loop until you set a complete flag like:

```
-(void) startT
{
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(tfun) toTarget:self withObject:nil ];

   do {

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];

   } while (!self.completed);
}
```

And in your tfun method

```
-(void) tfun
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   NSLog (@"Inside thread Function .. ");
   [pool drain];
   self.complete = YES;
}
```